# Converting String to hex and vise versa

Tags: java

Can anyone please help me in converting string to hex and hex to string for following string which is in arabic and english.

```
 String str = "مصطلحات : RAM : Random";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert String to Hex and Hex to String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020812/how-to-convert-string-to-hex-and-hex-to-string)

Answer (score 2):

```
byte[] myBytes = "مصطلحات : RAM : Random".getBytes("UTF-8");
String hexString = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(myBytes); // to hex String 

byte[] bytes = Hex.decodeHex(hexString.toCharArray());
new String(bytes, "UTF-8"); // decode it back
```

I used this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923863/converting-a-string-to-hexadecimal-in-java?answertab=votes#tab-top) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13991096/3014866)

Comment: Thanks #Rudziankou will give a try.