# How do I convert Text to HexaDecimal?

Tags: java, text, hex, converters

I am looking for a way or multiple ways (Always good to know many ways) how to convert Text (String) to HexaDecimal like this http://codebeautify.org/string-hex-converter

Any help would be appreciated.
I've been looking for hours around different places and I have so far found no code that could potentionally do this for me.

All the ways that this could be done is accepted, I love learning about coding.

Comment: Is it not a: [Converting A String To Hexadecimal In Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923863/converting-a-string-to-hexadecimal-in-java) or [How to convert String to Hex and Hex to String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020812/how-to-convert-string-to-hex-and-hex-to-string) or even [How can I convert a string into hex in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946597/how-can-i-convert-a-string-into-hex-in-java)

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? The best way to learn coding is by coding(and making mistakes).

Answer (score 0):

String to Hex:

```
Integer.decode(hexString);
```

Hex to String:

```
Integer.toHexString(integer);
```